# How to prevent fields from being dropped after an EDMX update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-generation, edmx, ef-database-first

I have an EF 5.0 Database First model based on the Oracle 11G database, as shown below:
[image: model]

**BaseEntity (abstract)**
Id

**BaseHistoricalEntity (abstract)**
EntityId
CreateDate
DeleteDate

**TitleEntity**
TitleNumber
IsDraft
RegistryDate
LastModified
LastModifiedBy
TitleStatusId
BuildTypeId
OkvedId
DeliveryDate
TitleBuildCharacteristics
TitleTypeId
BasePriceId
KOSGU

All the entities have a primary key (`Id`). Therefore they are derived from *BaseEntity*.

The *Title* table has additional three fields from *BaseHistoricalEntity* entity.

EntityId
CreateDate
DeleteDate

The *Title* table maps to three derived entities as follows:

> BaseEntity->BaseHistoricalEntity->TitleEntity

When I add/remove fields to/from other tables in the database and then update the EDMX model, the following field defenition are removed from the EDMX file:

```
<ScalarProperty Name="EntityId" ColumnName="ENTITY_ID" />
<ScalarProperty Name="CreateDate" ColumnName="CREATE_DATE" />
<ScalarProperty Name="DeleteDate" ColumnName="DELETE_DATE" />
```

What should I do to save these fields after a database change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2351
**EF Team Triage**: This is by design (albeit arguably a bad design). The Update Model From Database functionality is built to merge changes into the model that it created, if you start editing the model (adding inheritance etc.) then the wizard will not always be able to successfully merge changes. 
There are a lot of issues with Update Model From Database and we have ideas about how to re-create it in a way that would be much more robust. Unfortunately fixing the current implementation is not feasible.